# Spilt data by the middle points

Tags: r

My data set contains the following variables:

```
id = i.d.
rept = repeatition number
class = class type (constant per id)
x0 = initial points
x1 = middle point
x2 = final point


id <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
rept <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6)
class <- c("a","a","a","n","n","n","n","n","a","a","a","a","w","w","w","w","w","w")
x0 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5)
x1 <- c(.3,.3,.3,1.52,1.52,1.52,1.52,1.52,3.75,3.75,3.75,3.75, 4.55,4.55,4.55,4.55,4.55,4.55)
x2 <- c(2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6)

alldata <- data.frame(id,rept,class,x0,x1,x2)
```

which looks like

```
   id rept class x0   x1 x2
1   0    1     a  0 0.30  2
2   0    2     a  0 0.30  2
3   0    3     a  0 0.30  2
4   1    1     n  0 1.52  6
5   1    2     n  0 1.52  6
6   1    3     n  0 1.52  6
7   1    4     n  0 1.52  6
8   1    5     n  0 1.52  6
9   2    1     a  1 3.75  4
10  2    2     a  1 3.75  4
11  2    3     a  1 3.75  4
12  2    4     a  1 3.75  4
13  3    1     w  5 4.55  6
14  3    2     w  5 4.55  6
15  3    3     w  5 4.55  6
16  3    4     w  5 4.55  6
17  3    5     w  5 4.55  6
18  3    6     w  5 4.55  6
```

I want to split the data by the middle point. For example,

for id = 0, we have x0=0, x1=0.3, and x2=2

then the data will be split as follows:

```
0   0.3
0.3  1
1    2
```

Also, i need to define an indicator z = 0 before split and z = 1 after split. The variable "class" is constant across i.d. and would like to keep it in the new data set

The final data set is:

```
   id class   y0   y1 z
1   0     a 0.00 0.30 0
2   0     a 0.30 1.00 1
3   0     a 1.00 2.00 1
4   1     n 0.00 1.00 0
5   1     n 1.00 1.52 0
6   1     n 1.52 2.00 1
7   1     n 2.00 3.00 1
8   1     n 3.00 4.00 1
9   1     n 4.00 5.00 1
10  2     a 1.00 2.00 0
11  2     a 2.00 3.00 0
12  2     a 3.00 3.75 0
13  2     a 3.75 4.00 1
14  3     w 1.00 2.00 0
15  3     w 2.00 3.00 0
16  3     w 3.00 4.00 0
17  3     w 4.00 4.55 0
18  3     w 4.55 5.00 1
19  3     w 5.00 6.00 1
```

where y0 is the intial point, and y1 is the final point.

Comment: At the top, you have `x1 = middle point`, which implies it is always in the middle. However, in your example data, id 3 has `x0 = 5`, `x1 = 4.55`, and `x3 = 6`. So what is the meaning of `x1 = middle point` at the top if `x1` is not consistently the middle point?

Comment: Also, maybe this is just me, but when you say "the data will be split as follows:", I don't understand at all what follows. What is the meaning of rows and columns in the 3x2 matrix that follows?

Comment: @Gregor 1) there are different middle point for each unique id but similar per id, and 2) the 3*2 matrix is just the split for id=0.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve so many downvotes. If you have eyes, you can compare the desired output with that 3x2 matrix and draw *some* connection (it appears as the first three rows, in the `y`s). Sure, the question totally neglects to explain that x0 and x2 really, really do not at all determine the bounds of the sequence, but I've seen worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's translation from input to output isn't spelled out at all, but this works:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(alldata)
DT[, {
    x <- sort(c(x1[1], seq(from = min(x0[1],rept[1]), to = min(x2[1],rept[.N]))))
    list(y0 = head(x,-1), y1 = tail(x,-1), z = cumsum(head(x,-1)==x1[1]))
}, by=.(id,class)]
```

which gives

```
    id class   y0   y1 z
 1:  0     a 0.00 0.30 0
 2:  0     a 0.30 1.00 1
 3:  0     a 1.00 2.00 1
 4:  1     n 0.00 1.00 0
 5:  1     n 1.00 1.52 0
 6:  1     n 1.52 2.00 1
 7:  1     n 2.00 3.00 1
 8:  1     n 3.00 4.00 1
 9:  1     n 4.00 5.00 1
10:  2     a 1.00 2.00 0
11:  2     a 2.00 3.00 0
12:  2     a 3.00 3.75 0
13:  2     a 3.75 4.00 1
14:  3     w 1.00 2.00 0
15:  3     w 2.00 3.00 0
16:  3     w 3.00 4.00 0
17:  3     w 4.00 4.55 0
18:  3     w 4.55 5.00 1
19:  3     w 5.00 6.00 1
```

It's pretty clear how this can be done without the data.table package as well.